# error showing related to serviceFactory.create user

Tags: android

throwing exception

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.ServiceFactory.createUserAgent(ServiceFactory.java:44)

problem is happening in  sinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(this).userId(username).applicationKey(APP_KEY)
                .applicationSecret(APP_SECRET).environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT).build();

my code is:-

```
  @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> qry=ParseQuery.getQuery("_User");
    qry.whereEqualTo("username",(String)LoginFrag.name.getText().toString().trim());
    qry.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> obj, ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            if(e==null)
            {

         for (ParseObject dealsObject : obj) {
             username=(String) dealsObject.get("username");
                 startSinchClient(username);
                 Log.i("MessageService", "calling startSinchClient"+" "+username);

         }



            }


        }

    });



    broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    Log.i("MessageService", "broadcast started");
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
public void startSinchClient(String username) {

   sinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(this).userId(username).applicationKey("xxxxxx")
            .applicationSecret("xxxxxxxxxx").environmentHost("xxxxxxxxx").build();

    sinchClient.addSinchClientListener(this);

    sinchClient.setSupportMessaging(true);
    sinchClient.setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground(true);

    sinchClient.checkManifest();
    sinchClient.start();
}
```

checked properly the APP_KEY,SECRET_KEY and environment.

Comment: Without any code no chance! Add the essential parts.

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow. You should provide enough details for the issue you are facing, it would help you to get good answers.